# Sumar las cantidades por array con el metodo reduce o for (javascript)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ya se halló la suma de las cantidades de la variable tele, que de hecho en el código esta especificado cual es, ahora necesito sumarlos por array, me imagino que debe ser con un `for`, pero no se como implementarselo al método reduce, pues esto me saca toda la suma de las variables tele, pero necesito que me las saque por aparte, me podrían ayudar.Intenete hacerlo con la variable ens t de hecho me sale lo del array uno, pero concatenado más no sumado

```
Vue.config.devtools = true;
const v1 =new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data(){
        return{
        casa : '',
        ens : '',
        referencias: [
            //array(1)
            {nombre:'melisa', apellido:'carmona', 
            datos:[
                 **//suma de tele array (1)**
                {telefono :'claro', casa : 'medellín', tele :1.0000},
                {telefono :'claro', casa : 'medellín', tele :2.88989}
            ]},
            //array(2)
            {nombre:'andres', apellido:'sosa', 
            datos:[
                **//suma de tele array(2)**
                {telefono :'iphone', casa : 'amalfi', tele :2.4500},
                {telefono :'iphone', casa : 'amalfi', tele :9.6787}
            ]},
    ]
    }
},
methods:{
    mapearArr(){
            const casa = this.referencias.map((item)=>{
                return item.datos;
            });

            //Suma en general de la variable tele
            this.total = casa.reduce((total,item)=>{
                return total + item.reduce((total1, item1)=>{
                    return total1 + item1.tele;
                },0);
            }, 0)

            console.log(this.total); 
            **//este fue un ensayo de la suma de tele por array, pero solo 
            // saca el primer concatenado más no sumado**
            this.suma = this.ens.reduce((i, item)=>{
                return i + item.tele;
            }) 
            console.log(this.suma);


        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Hola melisa, me imagino que esta pregunta es continuación de otra pregunta anterior (por la referencia a la variable `tele`), deberías añadir algo más de contexto sobre lo que estás haciendo, cómo lo estás haciendo y los errores/dificultades que estés encontrando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar el contenido y formato de las preguntas. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor considera mejorar la redacción del párrafo, pues aunque no es extenso pero no se entiende

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer la suma por separado podŕias usar `.map` y luego `.reduce()` de cada elemento.

```js
const data = {referencias: [
    {nombre:'melisa', apellido:'carmona', 
    datos:[        
        {telefono :'claro', casa : 'medellín', tele :1.0000},
        {telefono :'claro', casa : 'medellín', tele :2.88989}
    ]},
    {nombre:'andres', apellido:'sosa', 
    datos:[       
        {telefono :'iphone', casa : 'amalfi', tele :2.4500},
        {telefono :'iphone', casa : 'amalfi', tele :9.6787}
    ]},
]};

const res = data.referencias.map(e=>e.datos.reduce((p,c)=>p+c.tele, 0));

console.log(res);
```